# How to open *.mht files from within a c++ program?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, createprocess, mhtml

I've a *.mht file (say, abc.mht) which opens in IE explorer manually.
I want to automate this process (programatically from c++) of 
1) opening the abc.mht file
2) Keeping it open for few seconds
3) Then, close the abc.mht file from within my c++ program.

I've been using the below command for running EXEs from my c++ code. But I can't use the similar analogy for opening *.mht files.

Can anyone plz help me to programatically open *.mht files. Thnaks.

```
STARTUPINFO sInfo;
    memset( &sInfo, 0, sizeof(sInfo) );
    sInfo.cb = sizeof(sInfo);
    sInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    sInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;
    memset( &pInfo, 0, sizeof(pInfo) );

    CreateProcess(NULL, _T(Path), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, _T(workDir), &sInfo, &pInfo))
```

Comment: CreateProcess() can only start executable files.  ShellExecuteEx() knows how to use a file association, a shell implementation detail.

Comment: Internet Explorer is automatable. You can use [this sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa752127.aspx) to open an Internet Explorer window and navigate it to your *.mht file. All that's missing is calling `pBrowser2->Quit()` when you want to close the window.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than specifying NULL as the application name, use **c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe** (or, your favorite browser).  Then, pass the path of the **.mht** file as the command line parameter.  To close the browser, you'll need to enumerate processes and post the appropriate message to the browser process.